# Is there and equivalent for Microsoft's UuidCompare, UuidCreate, etc in Linux or POSIX environment?

Tags: linux, posix, uuid

Is there an equivalent for Microsoft's UuidCompare, UuidCreate, etc in Linux or POSIX environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> libuuid is part of the e2fsprogs package.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#C

Comment: The real answer is no, but there is one that is close and it's libuuid. The calls are similar but different, so the library is not a drop in if you already are using the windows calls. Example: UuidCompare in MS is equal to uuid_compare in libuuid. -Crazychenz